# Get text inside span on clicked list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list which contains li items with value (site URL) and inside the list item, the name of the site within a span. I have global variables site, siteUrl and siteName and get the values on document ready. I'm not sure why but I can get the siteUrl to return the value of the clicked list item but not the siteName, which is the text inside the span. I'm not sure how to get the text inside the span of the clicked item.

JS:

```
siteUrl = null;
$("#expList li").click(function(){
    if(this.id != 'myList'){
        siteUrl =  $(this).attr('value');
        siteName = $(this).text();
        RefreshSiteInfo();
    }else{
        siteUrl =  $(this).attr('value');
        siteName = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
        RefreshSiteInfo();
    }
    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
    <ul id="expList" class="list"><li value="https://hosted.compulite.ca" class="collapsed expanded">
<span class="siteTitle">Sharepoint Demo Website</span>
<ul style="display: block;">
<li value="https://hosted.compulite.ca/academic" class="collapsed expanded"><span class="siteTitle">Academic</span>
<ul style="display: block;">
<li value="https://hosted.compulite.ca/academic/bm"><span class="siteTitle">Board Meetings</span></li>
<li value="https://hosted.compulite.ca/sandbox/trial"><span class="siteTitle">Trial</span></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li value="https://hosted.compulite.ca/service"><span class="siteTitle">Service</span></li>
<li value="https://hosted.compulite.ca/testing"><span class="siteTitle">DemoTesting</span></li>
<li value="https://hosted.compulite.ca/training"><span class="siteTitle">Training</span></li></ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's `RefreshSiteInfo()`?

Comment: sorry that's another function that populates some divs based on the siteUrl when i click a ilst item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).children('span').eq(0).text()
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` [isn't a valid property](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) on `li` elements within `ul` containers. For this you'll want to use [a `data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) and pull the data using [jQuery's `data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```html
...
<li data-value="foo" class="..." ...>...</li>
...
```

```js
...
siteUrl =  $(this).data('value');
...
```

Comment: Thanks but it's working fine for me. I'm trying to get the siteName to return the text.

Comment: @Batman I'm unable to replicate your issue (http://jsfiddle.net/MQWWt/). It's probably due to your invalid HTML. Run your HTML through [W3's validator](http://validator.w3.org) and fix the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Since the user can only click on the text within the `<span>` you might reference this from the event object that is passed to your function:

```
siteUrl = null;
$("#expList li").click(function(event){
    if(this.id != 'myList'){
        siteUrl =  $(this).attr('value');
        siteName = $(event.target).text();
        RefreshSiteInfo();
    }else{
        siteUrl =  $(this).attr('value');
        siteName = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
        RefreshSiteInfo();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FhXyZ/2/)

HTML:

```
<ul id="expList" class="list">
    <li data-value="https://hosted.compulite.ca" class="collapsed expanded">
        <span class="siteTitle">Sharepoint Demo Website</span>
        <ul style="display: block;">
            <li data-value="https://hosted.compulite.ca/academic" class="collapsed expanded">
                <span class="siteTitle">Academic</span>
                <ul style="display: block;">
                    <li data-value="https://hosted.compulite.ca/academic/bm">
                        <span class="siteTitle">Board Meetings</span>
                    </li>
                    <li data-value="https://hosted.compulite.ca/sandbox/trial">
                        <span class="siteTitle">Trial</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li data-value="https://hosted.compulite.ca/service">
                <span class="siteTitle">Service</span>
            </li>
            <li data-value="https://hosted.compulite.ca/testing">
                <span class="siteTitle">DemoTesting</span>
            </li>
            <li data-value="https://hosted.compulite.ca/training">
                <span class="siteTitle">Training</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQ:

```
var siteUrl  = '',
    siteName = '';

$("#expList li").click(function ( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    siteUrl = $(this).data('value');
    siteName = $(this).text();
    alert(siteUrl+' '+siteName);
    // RefreshSiteInfo();
});
```

Comment: This is how i create my list items in JS http://jsfiddle.net/VpTqp/  How should I change this code so that my list items contain data-value instead of value since it keeps getting brought up that I shouldn't be using value.

Comment: That's not going to work. This is how the html is created and appended http://jsfiddle.net/VpTqp/1/ if there a way I can change var li?

Comment: You're adding data-value to span instead of the li tag? Is that on purpose? I think I can modify it myself but I'm just wondering it there is a reason.

Comment: Didn't work for me. What if I did something like: $('<li data-value="'+item.url+'">'

Comment: K that didn't work. Owell, honestly, using value has worked for me so I'm not going to spend too much time on this. Thanks for trying.